# Flutter how to show users lat lng with multiple markers on google map?

Tags: flutter, google-maps-markers, latitude-longitude

I get the user `lat` `lng` while signup and now I want to show these on my map. I tried it but don't know how to show it form `json`. I need your help guys.

**Here is my Updated Code:**

```
class LocationPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const LocationPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LocationPage> createState() => _LocationPageState();
}

class _LocationPageState extends State<LocationPage> {
  late GoogleMapController mapController;
  Iterable markers = [];

  _markers(List<Data> locationInfo) {
    Iterable markers = Iterable.generate(locationInfo.length, (index) {
      return Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId(locationInfo[index].id.toString()),
          position: LatLng(
            double.parse(locationInfo[index].lat!),
            double.parse(locationInfo[index].lon!),
          ),
          infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: locationInfo[index].firstName));
    });

    return markers;
  }

  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    mapController = controller;
  }
  final List<Data> list = [];
  position: LatLng(24.491434, 54.368526))];
  static const _initialCameraPosition = CameraPosition(target: LatLng(24.491434, 54.368526), zoom: 17);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: SizedBox(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: double.infinity,
                child: GoogleMap(
                    myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
                    zoomControlsEnabled: false,
                    onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
                    markers: Set.from(markers),
                    initialCameraPosition: _initialCameraPosition),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And here is my User model

```
import 'dart:convert';

UsersByFilter usersByFilterFromJson(String str) => UsersByFilter.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String usersByFilterToJson(UsersByFilter data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class UsersByFilter {
  UsersByFilter({
    this.total,
    this.perPage,
    this.currentPage,
    this.lastPage,
    this.nextPageUrl,
    this.prevPageUrl,
    this.from,
    this.to,
    this.success,
    this.enMessage,
    this.arMessage,
    this.data,
    this.status,
  });

  UsersByFilter.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    total = json['total'];
    perPage = json['per_page'].toString();
    currentPage = json['current_page'].toString();
    lastPage = json['last_page'];
    nextPageUrl = json['next_page_url'];
    prevPageUrl = json['prev_page_url'];
    from = json['from'].toString();
    to = json['to'].toString();
    success = json['success'];
    enMessage = json['en_message'];
    arMessage = json['ar_message'];
    if (json['data'] != null) {
      data = [];
      json['data'].forEach((v) {
        data?.add(Data.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    status = json['status'];
  }

  int? total;
  String? perPage;
  String? currentPage;
  int? lastPage;
  String? nextPageUrl;
  String? prevPageUrl;
  String? from;
  String? to;
  bool? success;
  String? enMessage;
  String? arMessage;
  List<Data>? data;
  int? status;

  UsersByFilter copyWith({
    int? total,
    String? perPage,
    String? currentPage,
    int? lastPage,
    String? nextPageUrl,
    String? prevPageUrl,
    String? from,
    String? to,
    bool? success,
    String? enMessage,
    String? arMessage,
    List<Data>? data,
    int? status,
  }) =>
      UsersByFilter(
        total: total ?? this.total,
        perPage: perPage ?? this.perPage,
        currentPage: currentPage ?? this.currentPage,
        lastPage: lastPage ?? this.lastPage,
        nextPageUrl: nextPageUrl ?? this.nextPageUrl,
        prevPageUrl: prevPageUrl ?? this.prevPageUrl,
        from: from ?? this.from,
        to: to ?? this.to,
        success: success ?? this.success,
        enMessage: enMessage ?? this.enMessage,
        arMessage: arMessage ?? this.arMessage,
        data: data ?? this.data,
        status: status ?? this.status,
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final map = <String, dynamic>{};
    map['total'] = total;
    map['per_page'] = perPage;
    map['current_page'] = currentPage;
    map['last_page'] = lastPage;
    map['next_page_url'] = nextPageUrl;
    map['prev_page_url'] = prevPageUrl;
    map['from'] = from;
    map['to'] = to;
    map['success'] = success;
    map['en_message'] = enMessage;
    map['ar_message'] = arMessage;
    if (data != null) {
      map['data'] = data?.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    map['status'] = status;
    return map;
  }
}


Data dataFromJson(String str) => Data.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String dataToJson(Data data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Data {
  Data({
    this.id,
    this.username,
    this.type,
    this.customerId,
    this.lang,
    this.countryId,
    this.email,
    this.firstName,
    this.lastName,
    this.phone,
    this.address,
    this.location,
    this.dob,
    this.sex,
    this.city,
    this.createdAt,
    this.updatedAt,
    this.idPhoto,
    this.accessToken,
    this.accessTokenEnd,
    this.roleId,
    this.verified,
    this.verificationCode,
    this.passwordCode,
    this.fcmToken,
    this.mobile,
    this.bio,
    this.photo,
    this.lat,
    this.lon,
    this.verifiedSponsor,
    this.requests,
    this.isActive,
    this.categoryId,
    this.companyName,
    this.tradeLicense,
    this.field,
    this.workTime,
    this.facebook,
    this.linkedIn,
    this.instagram,
    this.whatsApp,
    this.wishlisted,
    this.fbId,
    this.googleToken,
    this.facebookToken,
    this.facebookId,
    this.googleId,
    this.balance,
    this.photos,
    this.role,
  });

  Data.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    id = json['id'];
    username = json['username'];
    type = json['type'];
    customerId = json['customer_id'];
    lang = json['lang'];
    countryId = json['country_id'];
    email = json['email'];
    firstName = json['first_name'];
    lastName = json['last_name'];
    phone = json['phone'];
    address = json['address'];
    location = json['location'];
    dob = json['dob'];
    sex = json['sex'];
    city = json['city'];
    createdAt = json['created_at'];
    updatedAt = json['updated_at'];
    idPhoto = json['id_photo'];
    accessToken = json['access_token'];
    accessTokenEnd = json['access_token_end'];
    roleId = json['role_id'];
    verified = json['verified'];
    verificationCode = json['verification_code'];
    passwordCode = json['password_code'];
    fcmToken = json['fcm_token'];
    mobile = json['mobile'];
    bio = json['bio'];
    photo = json['photo'];
    lat = json['lat'];
    lon = json['lon'];
    verifiedSponsor = json['verified_sponsor'];
    requests = json['requests'];
    isActive = json['is_active'];
    categoryId = json['category_id'];
    companyName = json['company_name'];
    tradeLicense = json['trade_license'];
    field = json['field'];
    workTime = json['work_time'];
    facebook=
    json["facebook"];
    linkedIn=
    json["linkedIn"];
    instagram=
    json["instagram"];
    whatsApp=
    json["whatsApp"];
    wishlisted=
    json["wishlisted"];
    fbId=
    json["fb_id"];
    googleToken=
    json["google_token"];
    facebookToken=
    json["facebook_token"];
    facebookId=
    json["facebook_id"];
    googleId=
    json["google_id"];
    if (json['balance'] != null) {
      balance = [];
      json['balance'].forEach((v) {
        balance?.add(Balance.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    if (json['photos'] != null) {
      photos = [];
      json['photos'].forEach((v) {
        photos?.add(v);
      });
    }
    role = json['role'] != null ? Role.fromJson(json['role']) : null;
  }

  int? id;
  String? username;
  int? type;
  int? customerId;
  int? lang;
  int? countryId;
  String? email;
  String? firstName;
  dynamic lastName;
  String? phone;
  String? address;
  dynamic location;
  dynamic dob;
  dynamic sex;
  dynamic city;
  String? createdAt;
  String? updatedAt;
  dynamic idPhoto;
  dynamic accessToken;
  dynamic accessTokenEnd;
  int? roleId;
  int? verified;
  String? verificationCode;
  String? passwordCode;
  String? fcmToken;
  String? mobile;
  String? bio;
  String? photo;
  String? lat;
  String? lon;
  int? verifiedSponsor;
  int? requests;
  int? isActive;
  String? categoryId;
  dynamic companyName;
  dynamic tradeLicense;
  dynamic field;
  dynamic workTime;
  String? facebook;
  String? linkedIn;
  String? instagram;
  String? whatsApp;
  bool? wishlisted;
  dynamic fbId;
  dynamic googleToken;
  dynamic facebookToken;
  dynamic facebookId;
  dynamic googleId;
  List<Balance>? balance;
  List<dynamic>? photos;
  Role? role;

  Data copyWith({
    int? id,
    String? username,
    int? type,
    int? customerId,
    int? lang,
    int? countryId,
    String? email,
    String? firstName,
    dynamic lastName,
    String? phone,
    String? address,
    dynamic location,
    dynamic dob,
    dynamic sex,
    dynamic city,
    String? createdAt,
    String? updatedAt,
    dynamic idPhoto,
    dynamic accessToken,
    dynamic accessTokenEnd,
    int? roleId,
    int? verified,
    String? verificationCode,
    String? passwordCode,
    dynamic fcmToken,
    String? mobile,
    dynamic bio,
    dynamic photo,
    dynamic lat,
    dynamic lon,
    int? verifiedSponsor,
    int? requests,
    int? isActive,
    String? categoryId,
    dynamic companyName,
    dynamic tradeLicense,
    dynamic field,
    dynamic workTime,
    String? facebook,
    String? linkedIn,
    String? instagram,
    String? whatsApp,
    bool? wishlisted,
    dynamic fbId,
    dynamic googleToken,
    dynamic facebookToken,
    dynamic facebookId,
    dynamic googleId,
    List<Balance>? balance,
    List<dynamic>? photos,
    Role? role,
  }) =>
      Data(
        id: id ?? this.id,
        username: username ?? this.username,
        type: type ?? this.type,
        customerId: customerId ?? this.customerId,
        lang: lang ?? this.lang,
        countryId: countryId ?? this.countryId,
        email: email ?? this.email,
        firstName: firstName ?? this.firstName,
        lastName: lastName ?? this.lastName,
        phone: phone ?? this.phone,
        address: address ?? this.address,
        location: location ?? this.location,
        dob: dob ?? this.dob,
        sex: sex ?? this.sex,
        city: city ?? this.city,
        createdAt: createdAt ?? this.createdAt,
        updatedAt: updatedAt ?? this.updatedAt,
        idPhoto: idPhoto ?? this.idPhoto,
        accessToken: accessToken ?? this.accessToken,
        accessTokenEnd: accessTokenEnd ?? this.accessTokenEnd,
        roleId: roleId ?? this.roleId,
        verified: verified ?? this.verified,
        verificationCode: verificationCode ?? this.verificationCode,
        passwordCode: passwordCode ?? this.passwordCode,
        fcmToken: fcmToken ?? this.fcmToken,
        mobile: mobile ?? this.mobile,
        bio: bio ?? this.bio,
        photo: photo ?? this.photo,
        lat: lat ?? this.lat,
        lon: lon ?? this.lon,
        verifiedSponsor: verifiedSponsor ?? this.verifiedSponsor,
        requests: requests ?? this.requests,
        isActive: isActive ?? this.isActive,
        categoryId: categoryId ?? this.categoryId,
        companyName: companyName ?? this.companyName,
        tradeLicense: tradeLicense ?? this.tradeLicense,
        field: field ?? this.field,
        workTime: workTime ?? this.workTime,
        facebook: facebook ?? this.facebook,
        linkedIn: linkedIn ?? this.linkedIn,
        instagram: instagram ?? this.instagram,
        whatsApp: whatsApp ?? this.whatsApp,
        wishlisted: wishlisted ?? this.wishlisted,
        fbId: fbId ?? this.fbId,
        googleToken: googleToken ?? this.googleToken,
        facebookToken: facebookToken ?? this.facebookToken,
        facebookId: facebookId ?? this.facebookId,
        googleId: googleId ?? this.googleId,
        balance: balance ?? this.balance,
        photos: photos ?? this.photos,
        role: role ?? this.role,
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final map = <String, dynamic>{};
    map['id'] = id;
    map['username'] = username;
    map['type'] = type;
    map['customer_id'] = customerId;
    map['lang'] = lang;
    map['country_id'] = countryId;
    map['email'] = email;
    map['first_name'] = firstName;
    map['last_name'] = lastName;
    map['phone'] = phone;
    map['address'] = address;
    map['location'] = location;
    map['dob'] = dob;
    map['sex'] = sex;
    map['city'] = city;
    map['created_at'] = createdAt;
    map['updated_at'] = updatedAt;
    map['id_photo'] = idPhoto;
    map['access_token'] = accessToken;
    map['access_token_end'] = accessTokenEnd;
    map['role_id'] = roleId;
    map['verified'] = verified;
    map['verification_code'] = verificationCode;
    map['password_code'] = passwordCode;
    map['fcm_token'] = fcmToken;
    map['mobile'] = mobile;
    map['bio'] = bio;
    map['photo'] = photo;
    map['lat'] = lat;
    map['lon'] = lon;
    map['verified_sponsor'] = verifiedSponsor;
    map['requests'] = requests;
    map['is_active'] = isActive;
    map['category_id'] = categoryId;
    map['company_name'] = companyName;
    map['trade_license'] = tradeLicense;
    map['field'] = field;
    map['work_time'] = workTime;
    map['facebook'] = facebook;
    map['linkedIn'] = linkedIn;
    map['instagram'] = instagram;
    map['whatsApp'] = whatsApp;
    map['fb_id'] = fbId;
    map['google_token'] = googleToken;
    map['facebook_token'] = facebookToken;
    map['facebook_id'] = facebookId;
    map['google_id'] = googleId;
    if (balance != null) {
      map['balance'] = balance?.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    if (photos != null) {
      map['photos'] = photos?.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    if (role != null) {
      map['role'] = role?.toJson();
    }
    return map;
  }
}

Role roleFromJson(String str) => Role.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String roleToJson(Role data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Role {
  Role({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.createdAt,
    this.updatedAt,
  });

  Role.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
    createdAt = json['created_at'];
    updatedAt = json['updated_at'];
  }

  int? id;
  String? name;
  dynamic createdAt;
  dynamic updatedAt;

  Role copyWith({
    int? id,
    String? name,
    dynamic createdAt,
    dynamic updatedAt,
  }) =>
      Role(
        id: id ?? this.id,
        name: name ?? this.name,
        createdAt: createdAt ?? this.createdAt,
        updatedAt: updatedAt ?? this.updatedAt,
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final map = <String, dynamic>{};
    map['id'] = id;
    map['name'] = name;
    map['created_at'] = createdAt;
    map['updated_at'] = updatedAt;
    return map;
  }
}

Balance balanceFromJson(String str) => Balance.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String balanceToJson(Balance data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Balance {
  Balance({
    this.currency,
    this.value,
  });

  Balance.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    currency = json['currency'];
    value = json['value'];
  }

  String? currency;
  int? value;

  Balance copyWith({
    String? currency,
    int? value,
  }) =>
      Balance(
        currency: currency ?? this.currency,
        value: value ?? this.value,
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final map = <String, dynamic>{};
    map['currency'] = currency;
    map['value'] = value;
    return map;
  }
}
```

**My Api of geting users:**

```
static Future<http.Response> getUsers(Map<String, dynamic> params) async {
    var uri = Uri.parse(baseUrl + "Users/index").replace(queryParameters: params);
    var response = await http.get(uri, headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer ${Get.put(AppController()).loginResponse?.data?.token ?? ""}"});
    return response;
  }
}
```

**and Here I'm useing `changeNotifier`** :

```
class CategoryDetailService extends ChangeNotifier {
  UsersByFilter? usersByFilter;
  int offSet = 1;
  List<Data>? data = [];

  bool isLoading=false;

  fetchData(BuildContext context, String id) async {
    Map<String, dynamic> filter = {};
    log("Category id------" + id);
    filter["category_id"] = id;
    filter["per_page"] = "15";
    filter["offset"] = "15";
    filter["limit"] = "15";
    filter["role_id"] = "${Get.put(AppController()).roleId??0}";
    filter["page"] = "$offSet";

    log(jsonEncode(filter));

    var connectivityResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
    if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.mobile || connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
      isLoading = true;
      notifyListeners();
      Utils.showLoader(context);
      if (offSet == 1 || usersByFilter!.nextPageUrl != "") {
        ApiCall.getUsers(filter).then((value) async {
          isLoading = false;
          notifyListeners();
          if (value.statusCode == 200) {
            if (json.decode(value.body)["success"] != null) {
              if (json.decode(value.body)["success"]) {
                usersByFilter = UsersByFilter.fromJson(json.decode(value.body));
                log((usersByFilter?.data ?? []).length.toString());
                (data ?? []).addAll(usersByFilter?.data ?? []);
                if ((usersByFilter?.data ?? []).isNotEmpty) {
                  offSet = offSet + 1;
                }
                notifyListeners();
                Get.back();
                notifyListeners();
              } else {
                if (Get.put(AppController()).isEnglish()) {
                  Utils.flushBarErrorMessage(
                      jsonDecode(value.body)["en_message"], context);
                } else {
                  Utils.flushBarErrorMessage(
                      jsonDecode(value.body)["ar_message"], context);
                }
                Get.back();
              }
            } else {
              Utils.flushBarErrorMessage(
                  jsonDecode(value.body)["error"], context);
              Get.back();
            }
          }
          else {
            Utils.flushBarErrorMessage(
                LanguageStringKeys.instance.InvalidData.tr, context);
            Get.back();
          }
        }).catchError((onError, stackTrace) {
          Get.back();
          Utils.flushBarErrorMessage(
              LanguageStringKeys.instance.ThereIsSomeProblem.tr, context);
          log("my Error");
          debugPrint(onError.toString());
          debugPrint(stackTrace.toString());
        });
      }
      else{
        isLoading= false;
        notifyListeners();
        Get.back();
      }
    }else {
        Get.back();
        Utils.flushBarErrorMessage(
            LanguageStringKeys.instance.NoInternet.tr, context);
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code.

**changeNotifer**

```
class CategoryDetailService extends ChangeNotifier {
  UsersByFilter? usersByFilter;
  int offSet = 1;
  List<Data>? data = [];
  bool isLoading = false;
  Iterable markers = [];

  fetchData(BuildContext context, String id) async {
    Map<String, dynamic> filter = {};
    filter["category_id"] = id;
    filter["per_page"] = "15";
    filter["offset"] = "15";
    filter["limit"] = "15";
    filter["role_id"] = "${Get.put(AppController()).roleId ?? 0}";
    filter["page"] = "$offSet";

    var connectivityResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
    if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.mobile || connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
      isLoading = true;
      notifyListeners();
      Utils.showLoader(context);
      if (offSet == 1 || usersByFilter!.nextPageUrl != "") {
        ApiCall.getUsers(filter).then((value) async {
          isLoading = false;
          notifyListeners();
          if (value.statusCode == 200) {
            if (json.decode(value.body)["success"] != null) {
              if (json.decode(value.body)["success"]) {
                usersByFilter = UsersByFilter.fromJson(json.decode(value.body));
                (data ?? []).addAll(usersByFilter?.data ?? []);
                markers = _markers(data!);
                if ((usersByFilter?.data ?? []).isNotEmpty) {
                  offSet = offSet + 1;
                }
                notifyListeners();
                Get.back();
                notifyListeners();
              } else {
                if (Get.put(AppController()).isEnglish()) {
                  Utils.flushBarErrorMessage(jsonDecode(value.body)["en_message"], context);
                } else {
                  Utils.flushBarErrorMessage(jsonDecode(value.body)["ar_message"], context);
                }
                Get.back();
              }
            } else {
              Utils.flushBarErrorMessage(jsonDecode(value.body)["error"], context);
              Get.back();
            }
          } else {
            Utils.flushBarErrorMessage(LanguageStringKeys.instance.InvalidData.tr, context);
            Get.back();
          }
        }).catchError((onError, stackTrace) {
          Get.back();
          Utils.flushBarErrorMessage(LanguageStringKeys.instance.ThereIsSomeProblem.tr, context);
          log("my Error");
          debugPrint(onError.toString());
          debugPrint(stackTrace.toString());
        });
      } else {
        isLoading = false;
        notifyListeners();
        Get.back();
      }
    } else {
      Get.back();
      Utils.flushBarErrorMessage(LanguageStringKeys.instance.NoInternet.tr, context);
    }
  }

  _markers(List<Data> locationInfo) {
    Iterable markers = Iterable.generate(locationInfo.length, (index) {
      return Marker(
          markerId: MarkerId(locationInfo[index].id.toString()),
          position: LatLng(
            double.parse(locationInfo[index].lat!),
            double.parse(locationInfo[index].lon!),
          ),
          infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: locationInfo[index].firstName));
    });
    return markers;
  }
}
```

**Page**

```
class LocationPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const LocationPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LocationPage> createState() => _LocationPageState();
}

class _LocationPageState extends State<LocationPage> {
  late GoogleMapController mapController;
  static const _initialCameraPosition = CameraPosition(target: LatLng(24.491434, 54.368526), zoom: 17);

  void _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    mapController = controller;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: SizedBox(
                width: double.infinity,
                height: double.infinity,
                child: GoogleMap(
                    myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
                    zoomControlsEnabled: false,
                    onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
                    markers: Set.from(CategoryDetailService().markers),
                    initialCameraPosition: _initialCameraPosition),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

No change on other codes. you can use your old codes.

Comment: markers are not showing after run this code.

Comment: Any error ? Pls debug code

Comment: no error, code is working fine but with no marker

Comment: after debug I notice that I'm getting 0 size of markers.

Comment: what is the length of the data ?

Comment: there are total 66 users